# onTriggerEnter2D fires only once if object doesn't move

Tags: unity-game-engine

So I'm building an 2D metroidvania-like action game.

---

I have a player, with:

---

- rigidbody2d
- a polygon collider, non-trigger
- a box collider, is trigger, enabled = false, this one is the attack collider

---

And when I hit attack key, I set enabled to true for like 0.5 seconds, and then set it back to false.

I kept an eye on the check box besides the collider, and I'm sure this set enabled true and false is working properly.

---

Then I create another target object, with:

---

- a polygon collider, non-trigger

---

When the target object has onTriggerEnter2D fires, I log it.

---

So ideally I will make some damage on the target when the onTriggerEnter2D fires.

---

However, if I let the player stand still and hit the target multiple times, onTriggerEnter2D will fire only once, I have to move my player a little bit, and hit target, to fire the function again.

I also logged it when onTriggerExit2D fires, so I am sure it exits. it just doesn't enter anymore.

---

Another thing is, if I attack fast and hit the target continuously, the function does fire as many times as I hit it.

but if i stop a while (like 1 second?), and I hit it again, function doesn't fire. i still have to make the player walk a little bit to fire the function again.

---

this situation happens only when:

( all collider on the target object are non-trigger )  OR  ( target has rigidbody2D attached )

If I remove rigidbody2D, and add one isTrigger collider on the target, this thing will not happen.

---

Anyone can help me with it? I have no idea what causes this.

Thanks!

Comment: Try OnTriggerStay2D() it gets called every frame on which there is a collision

Comment: Please provide a minimal example in code that your problem describes

Comment: I also posted this question on unity answers, and I see some confusion around it. So what I am doing is, for each attack, I enabled the isTrigger collider, and then disabled it, so it should get multiple onTriggerEnter fires for multiple attacks. and right now it only fires once.

Comment: please add your code to the question